# Getting `error: invalid resource name` while doing `kubectl get pod`

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I run `kubectl get pod` which gives me following output:

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs   1/1     Running   3 (49m ago)   31d
```

I am not able to get utilization of this pod even after specifying its name in different ways. I gives `error: invalid resource name`:

```
$ kubectl top pod pod/spring-boot-k8s -n efault --containers
error: invalid resource name "pod/spring-boot-k8s": [may not contain '/']

$ kubectl top pod spring-boot-k8s -n efault --containers
Error from server (NotFound): pod "spring-boot-k8s" not found

$ kubectl top pod spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs -n efault --containers
Error from server (NotFound): pod "spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs" not found

$ kubectl top pod pod/spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs -n efault --containers
error: invalid resource name "pod/spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs": [may not contain '/']
```

My metric server is already running:

```
$ kubectl get all -n kube-system | grep metric
pod/metrics-server-6b76bd68b6-f68f4    1/1     Running   68 (54m ago)   38d
service/metrics-server   ClusterIP   10.103.98.14   <none>        443/TCP                  38d
deployment.apps/metrics-server   1/1     1            1           38d
replicaset.apps/metrics-server-6b76bd68b6   1         1         1       38d
```

Also I can see node utilization with `kubectl top node`:

```
$ kubectl top node
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
minikube   132m         1%     734Mi           4%
```

But I cannot see the CPU utilization of the pod:

```
$ kubectl top pod
error: Metrics not available for pod default/spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs, age: 747h9m12.416340419s
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a bug as discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13969) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/1061).

The easy solution is to stop and start minikube with housekeeping interval argument:

```
$ minikube stop

$ minikube start --extra-config=kubelet.housekeeping-interval=10s
```

After this, I was able to get the pod CPU utilization:

```
$ kubectl top pod
NAME                               CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
spring-boot-k8s-556b578645-pwdhs   2m           97Mi
```